# Developing a syntax for a language i'm thinking about designing

Tags: syntax, programming-languages, qbasic

I'm thinking about desiging a language similar to qbasic in syntax but even simpler so that a new programmer can learn some programming without being discouraged by something like C,C++, or C#. For example, use

```
Write "Hello World"
```

instead of

```
PRINT "Hello World"
```

or

```
In "Enter your name" 
Read = name
```

instead of

```
INPUT "Enter you name" name$
```

I'm looking for more suggestions on my syntax. Anything would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `Read = name` looks a lot like you're assigning the value of `name` to `Read`, though I gather it would actually do the opposite. That seems pretty unintuitive to me.

Comment: thanks. any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, my suggestion would be `name = Read()`. I.e. `Read` is a function which reads a string and returns it, `FunctionName()` calls a function without arguments, and `variableName = expression` evaluates `expression` and assigns the result to the variable `variableName`. I know that's kind of boring, because that's how most languages do it, but I really think it's the least confusing way.

Comment: I fail to see how `Write` is better than `PRINT`.  Either needs a bit of explanation, and only a bit.  `name = Read` is a possible approach (see SNOBOL), but I really don't see it as simpler than `INPUT`, or much simpler than `cout << "Enter your name:\n"; cin >> name;`.  Most modern languages are well enough designed that writing simple programs is more of a programming than a language problem.  It may be that there's a simpler solution that we've been missing for the past fifty or sixty years, but simply making qbasic maybe a touch more intuitive for you isn't it.

Comment: i like that sugggestion. Thank you very much! I wish there were more people on stack overflow like you who actually help instead of just being negative!

Comment: but for example why, if you are trying to make a beginner language use tokens like cin and cout instead of something easier to make sense of like in and out and also the \n and >><< stuff can get pretty confusing.

Comment: Someone who can't get used to `cin << "..."` instead of `PRINT "..."` after a decent explanation has no business being a (beginning) programmer. No program will ever look like english (which is a good thing(tm) btw), and it will always take some knowledge of the language (e.g. knowing `cout` and how it abuses `<<`) to understand a nontrivial program. The main thing is being understood by halfway decent programmers, and those don't care whether it says `PRINT` or `cout <<` or `QWERTY:::` as long is it can be easily identified. Needless to say, the last won't get loved.

Comment: @RCProgramming:  The issue with being negative is that there are things that cannot be done, or should not be done, or aren't nearly worth the effort.  This is the exact sort of thing I tried when I had learned much of BASIC.  It was pointless then, and unless you have some ideas I haven't seen it's pointless now.  I really doubt that, with all the good will and help in the world, you'll come up with anything noticeably better than Python or Scheme - unless you come up with a great idea, and you won't get one by asking for one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've looked into other pre-existing languages and found them wanting... OK, I'm sorry, but you're leaping into a seriously complicated subject by wanting to design your own language. Well defined (and supported) languages such as [Logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_%28programming_language%29), [BBC BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC_BASIC) (a personal favourite of mine) and (my 3 year old loves this) [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) are all very simple to pick up.

Assuming you're going forward with this, then take a look at [Domain Specific Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and also consider purchasing [the book of the same title](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Domain-Specific-Languages-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321712943) (no affiliate link) by the renowned Martin Fowler et al.

**Edited to include syntax examples:**

BBC Basic RSS feed reader

```
INSTALL @lib$+"XMLLIB"

      url$ = "http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/rss/5day/id/2688.xml"
      XMLfile$ = @tmp$+"temp.xml"
      PROCurldownload(url$, XMLfile$)

      PROC_initXML(xml{}, XMLfile$)
      rss% = FN_skipTo(xml{}, "rss", 0)
      IF rss% THEN
        channel% = FN_skipTo(xml{}, "channel", rss%)
        IF channel% THEN
          IF FN_skipTo(xml{}, "title", channel%) THEN
            PRINT FN_repEnt(FN_nextToken(xml{}))
          ENDIF
          WHILE FN_skipTo(xml{}, "item", channel%)
            item% = FN_getLevel(xml{})
            IF FN_skipTo(xml{}, "title", item%) THEN
              PRINT 'FN_repEnt(FN_nextToken(xml{}))
            ENDIF
          ENDWHILE
        ENDIF
      ENDIF
      PROC_exitXML(xml{})
      END
```

Logo:

```
FD 20    ; drawing a line and moving
PENUP    ; lifting the pen so it will not draw anything
FD 20    ; moving but not drawing
PENDOWN  ; lowering the pen so it draws again
FD 20    ; drawing a line and moving
PENUP    ; lifting the pen so it will not draw anything
FD 40    ; moving but not drawing
PENDOWN  ; lowering the pen so it draws again
RT 20    ; rotating right (clockwise) 20 degrees
```

Scratch:

You need to see the visual editor really

[image]

Comment: could you please give me example code from those 3 languages? Thanks

Comment: @RCProgramming: Google is your friend, I think... :-)

Comment: @RCProgramming Edited as requested

Comment: Thanks. I take it logo is a graphics only language? What is the difference between BBC basic and others. What would hello world look like?

Comment: @RCProgramming You're at the point now where you need to conduct your own research. Follow the links I've supplied and spend a lot of time thinking through your language before you commit to writing a parser.